# iOS - Add A Void SuccessCallback Block In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm pretty new to Swift. How do I define a function that has a VOID success callback block and a error callback block? I don't need to pass any objects on success, but I do need to know my error.

Example of a function using both success and error callback blocks that pass objects:

```
func searchForTweetsWithKeyword(searchString: String, geoCodeParameter: String, successCallback: (tweets :[Tweet]) ->(), errorCallback: (errorDictionary: Dictionary<String, String>) ->()) {
    ...do stuff
}
```

I want to accomplish something like this, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly syntax wise:

```
func validateNewItemWithDescription(description: String, quantity: Int, successCallback: () ->(Void), errorCallback: (errorString: String) ->())
{

}
```

Comment: () -> () would do it?

Comment: So what's wrong with `validateNewitemWithDescription`? it has two callback blocks, one of them is Void. You can also use (as an option) `()->()` because Void is an empty tuple - `()`

Comment: Would (Void) ->() also be correct?

Comment: @Rafi, the same but you should decide what's the best for you. The most popular style is to use () -> Void. See http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/11/swift-vs-void/

Comment: Rafi, why don't you just go ahead and try it out to see for yourself :) That is the best way to learn.

Comment: Thanks guys, and you're right @GuyDaher. I'm just trying to confirm just in case it works for me now, but I end up getting additional unwanted behavior just in case Swift does things extra differently from Objective-C.

Comment: What's wrong with a single callback that receives an optional error. If the error is nil then the call was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you definitely need two callback blocks? How about like call:

```
func parseCommand (inText: String) -> CommandParseResult
```

With CommandParseResult:

```
enum CommandParseResult{
case ValidCommand (Command)
case ErrorResponse (String) }
```

Then handle something like:

```
        var validCommand: Command?
        let commandResult = self.myDictionary.parseCommand(textCommand)
        switch commandResult
        {
            case .ErrorResponse (let errorResponse):
                completionMessage = errorResponse.stringByReplacingCaseFormat("<Person>", withString: self.currentPerson)
            case .ValidCommand (let returnedCommand):
                validCommand = returnedCommand
        }
```